# How to read two columns using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How to read two columns the first of which contains letters and the second of the values.

```
C0      -0.158040
C1      -0.157117
C2      -0.143805
C3      -0.140561
S4      0.059175
H5      0.128940
H6      0.129007
H7      0.142421
H8      0.139979
```

I often used this script below (it works for two or more columns), but not for this time !!

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
    f=[x.strip() for x in f if x.strip()]
    data=[tuple(map(float,x.split())) for x in f[2:]]
    oX=[x[0] for x in data]
    oY=[x[1] for x in data]
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You could use `pandas.read_csv`, would it be okay with you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution:

```
import csv

with open('file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        res = row[0].split()
        oX = res[0]
        oY = res[1]
        print (oX, oY)
```

output:

```
('C0', '-0.158040')
('C1', '-0.157117')
('C2', '-0.143805')
('C3', '-0.140561')
('S4', '0.059175')
('H5', '0.128940')
('H6', '0.129007')
('H7', '0.142421')
('H8', '0.139979')
```

Answer (score 2):

> Pandas is the way to go if you want to play around data from csv file.
>   It saves you from unnecessary iterations and makes data manipulation
>   easy

.

You can load file into a pandas data frame

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

Then select the required columns

```
df_temp = df.iloc[:,0:2]
```

To get pair of row values you can then use a tolist() function

```
df.values.tolist()
```

Output

```
[['C1', -0.157117], ['C2', -0.143805], ['C3', -0.140561], ['S4', 0.059175], ['H5', 0.12894], ['H6', 0.12900699999999998], ['H7', 0.142421], ['H8', 0.139979]]
```

Comment: Thank you, Amarpreet Singh.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any libraries at all, let alone pandas or re. Just read the file and use list comprehensions plus string methods to extract the data.

```
with open('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

oX = [line.replace('\n', '').split(',')[0] for line in data]
oY = [float(line.replace('\n', '').split(',')[1]) for line in data]
```

If you want each label paired with it's value you can zip them up.

```
paired = zip(ox, oY)
```

Comment: Thank you Apollo2020.   but for oY to generates an error:                    IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Is the data file comma delimited or is it tab delimited? The example you provided showed tab-delimited data but I assumed you presented it that way for ease of reading. Since the file is named file.csv, I assumed that it is actually a comma-separated value file. If it is actually CSV, it's hard to know the source of the error without looking at the file. It is probably a stray comma somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If the separator contains a variable number of space chars:

```
import csv
with open('myfile.csv', newline='') as cf:
   cfr = csv.reader(cf, delimiter=' ')
   oX=[]
   oY=[]
   for row in cfr:
       oX.append(row[0])
       oY.append(float(row[-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

A lazy solution using `numpy.loadtxt` might be:

```
labels = numpy.loadtxt(fileName, dtype=np.str, usecols=[0])
values = numpy.loadtxt(fileName, dtype=np.float64, usecols=[1])
pairs = numpy.stack((labels, values), axis=-1)
```